# Conditional list element in Ansible YAML

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a playbook to deploy consul in docker containers on our servers. I basically looks like this:

```
- name: run consul
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: consul | run consul servers and agents
      docker_container:
        name: consul
        network_mode: bridge
        published_ports:
          - "{{ docker_host_ip }}:8301:8301"
          - "{% if consul_server is defined %}{{ docker_host_ip }}:8300:8300{% endif %}"
...
```

... except the last line isn't working. I only want to expose port 8300 if consul is deployed as server which is stored in the `consul_server` variable for each host.

How do I conditionally append an element to a YAML list/array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) are your friends.

---

```
- set_fact:
   myTrue  : true
   myFalse : false
   myList  :
    - first
   myAdd   :
    - second

- debug:
    msg: "When TRUE: {{ myTrue |
           ternary( myList | union( myAdd ), myList ) }}"

- debug:
    msg: "When FALSE: {{ myFalse |
           ternary( myList | union( myAdd ), myList ) }}"
```

Output (slightly modified to remove irrelevancies):

```
TASK [test : debug] 
     "msg": "When TRUE: [u'first', u'second']"

TASK [test : debug] 
     "msg": "When FALSE: [u'first']"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the array concat:

```
- name: consul | run consul servers and agents
  docker_container:
    name: consul
    network_mode: bridge
    published_ports: "{{ [ docker_host_ip ~ ':8301:8301' ] + ([ docker_host_ip ~ ':8300:8300' ] if consul_server is defined else [])}}"
```

In the example code, the `{{ docker_host_ip }}:8300:8300` will be added to list, if `consul_server` is defined.